# Freeing a binary tree data structure in C

Tags: c, tree, memory-management

I have this function that I hope to be a good alternative to the recursive (thus performance expensive) approach.

```
#define _free_all(node, yes_no) \
    do { \
        Tree *__i;
        for (__i = node; __i; __i = __i->yes_no); \
        free(; node != __i; __i = __i->parent) { \
            free(__i->value); \
            free(__i); \
        } \
    } while (0)

void Tree_destroy(tree)
    Tree *tree;
{ /* Destroys a Tree object - Non Recursive */
    if (!tree)
        return;
    _free_all(tree, yes);
    _free_all(tree, no);

    if (tree->parent) {
        if (tree->parent->no == info)
            tree->parent->no = NULL;
        else
            tree->parent->yes = NULL;
    }
    free(tree);
}
```

The two children of each parent are `no` and `yes`.

Are there any issues with this approach ?

Comment: How are `Info` and `Tree` defined?

Comment: @OlafDietsche: Nothing, I just forgot to rename it. I corrected that.

Comment: Names starting with `_` and `__` are [reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10687114/1198654) and best if avoided.

Comment: Have you actually tested this code?  It doesn't free the whole tree.  The `free_all` macro either frees only left nodes or only right nodes, which means that any node in your tree that isn't on the left edge or right edge won't be freed.

Comment: JS1's comment is exactly the kind of thing I was going to warn about; binary trees and recursion are so intimately tied that any iterative function to do the same work will probably be horrendously complicated, which could lead to missed edge cases, leading to segfaults and memory leaks.

Comment: @tsleyson: So ... What shall I do to avoid recursion .. ?

Comment: I'm not a very experienced C programmer, so don't take this too seriously, but I would just use recursion. If freeing things were a major bottleneck, I might also analyze my code to see if there was some way to minimize the making and freeing of BSTs, maybe by reusing allocated nodes, or search for another way to represent the BST where the nodes are in a contiguous block of memory that can be freed all at once (similar to a binary heap stored in an array). I might also look into a gc to help amortize the cost of freeing objects. Like I said, grain of salt.

Comment: @tsleyson: Well, your suggestions are just strategies to cope with slow recursion for a limited number of BSTs, and that's __okay__ .. But what if I have thousands of BSTs for a complicated system that has no better way of storing its data than binary trees .. How can we do it then ?

Comment: Given my lack of experience with C and lack of knowledge of the internal workings of your system, I'm going to hang myself if I go too much further, so I'll stop after this. But I would really examine that assumption that there is no better way at all to store the data. There are tons of data structures out there, with tons of clever tricks to optimize for any resource we can think of. If your requirements are that extreme, it might be worth it to look into the more obscure ones. Off the top of my head, [B-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) could be a viable alternative for your case.

Comment: @tsleyson: Thank you for this. So, the discussion is settled that the usage of binary trees is only useful if you can cope with recursion, right ?

Comment: Well, there are ways to implement BST algorithms without recursion, but the implementations I've seen are pretty complicated. Most involve managing your own stack to replicate what the runtime system does when you use recursion. If you miss some edge case, you could get mysterious bugs far down the line and spend a lot of time debugging. I'd first try to solve things at the data structure level. For me it's a lot nicer (and more fun) to implement a suitable data structure than to debug memory leaks and segmentation faults, and you'll have more example code and more theory to back you up.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Bug

[JS1 is quite correct](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69897/freeing-a-binary-tree-data-structure-in-c#comment127775_69897) to point out that this does not work: it never visits or frees `tree->yes->no` (among other nodes).

#### 2. Correct algorithm

Consider a finite state machine with three states:

1. If *tree* has a left child, set *tree* to its left child and go to state 1. Otherwise, go to state 2.
2. If *tree* has a right child, set *tree* to its right child and go to state 1. Otherwise, go to state 3.
3. (In this state *tree* has no children.) Destroy *tree*. If *tree* had no parent, stop. Otherwise, delete whichever of *parent*'s children is equal to *tree*, set *tree* to *parent* and go to state 1.

This state machine walks the tree in post-order, destroying each node after destroying all of its descendant nodes. Here's one way of translating this into C:

```
void TreeDestroy(Tree *tree)
{
    for (;;) {
        if (tree->left) {
            tree = tree->left;
        } else if (tree->right) {
            tree = tree->right;
        } else {
            Tree *parent = tree->parent;
            free(tree->value);
            free(tree);
            if (!parent)
                break;
            else if (parent->left == tree)
                parent->left = NULL;
            else if (!parent->left && parent->right == tree)
                parent->right = NULL;
            else
                assert(0); /* can't happen if tree is well-formed */
            tree = parent;
        }
    }
}
```

(I've used "left" and "right" here because these are the more usual names for the two children of a node in a binary tree.)

#### 3. What if there are no parent pointers?

To iteratively destroy a binary tree with no parent pointers, start with the *rotate right* operation:

[image: rotate right]

```
void TreeRotateRight(Tree **tree)
{
    Tree *left = (*tree)->left;
    (*tree)->left = left->right;
    left->right = *tree;
    *tree = left;
}
```

By repeatedly applying the *rotate right* operation, you can turn a tree into a *vine*. (A vine is a degenerate tree in which nodes only have right children.)

```
void TreeToVine(Tree **tree)
{
    while (*tree) {
        while ((*tree)->left)
            TreeRotateRight(tree);
        tree = &((*tree)->right);
    }
}
```

And then a vine is easy to destroy iteratively:

```
void TreeDestroy(Tree *tree)
{
    TreeToVine(&tree);
    while (tree) {
        assert(!tree->left);
        Tree *right = tree->right;
        free(tree->value);
        free(tree);
        tree = right;
    }
}
```